# App crashes when using MagicalRecord in release build

Tags: magicalrecord

Our app uses MagicalRecord to store data in Core Data. It have worked fine so far, but now, after adding fields to my tables, the app crashes, but only in release builds.

When I upgrade via cable, it works just fine, but when I use Ad-Hoc (Enterprise) distribtion to upgrade the app, the app crashes.

The problem is I don't get any debug data on the crash because of this. The only thing I get is a "exited abnormally with signal 11: Segmentation fault: 11" error.

Crash report:
(http://pastebin.com/64c4jvgJ)

I assume the issue might be related to needing migration, but I can't find any good documentation on how this is supposed to work. Any pointers in the right direction is welcome.

Update:
More info - 
Before updating my datamodel, i had a store called PAM.sqlite, and a non-versioned store called PAM.xcdatamodeld. Now i have a versioned store, called PAM & PAM 2.

I use this code to attempt an automigration, but it does not work:

```
[MagicalRecord setDefaultModelNamed:@"PAM 2.xcdatamodel"];
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"PAM.sqlite"];
```

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? Having the same problem...

Comment: @gillyD: you can [see my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532724/app-crashes-when-using-magicalrecord-in-release-build/#answer-32779414)

Comment: Yes - thanks for posting.

Comment: @thomassnielsen: don't forget to choose the right answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the extenstion of the data model (e.g. **`MyProjectDB.momd`**)

so, the code syntax would be:

```
  [MagicalRecord setDefaultModelNamed:@"MyProjectDB.momd"];
```

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181662/magicalrecord-in-a-static-library-how-do-i-load-the-data-model#comment-41791655)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Try to add new version in xcdatamodeld. Then activate it as current. Open it in finder. Choose show package content. You will see two files for both of your versions. Replace the one for old version with non-versioned file from your old build. Use this

```
[MagicalRecord setupCoreDataStackWithAutoMigratingSqliteStoreNamed:@"PAM.sqlite"];
```

So your project will have two versions of db. And will have an ability to migrate automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Default settings of MagicalRecord for iOS (https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord)  is something like this

```
#ifdef DEBUG
[self setShouldDeleteStoreOnModelMismatch:YES];
#else
[self setShouldDeleteStoreOnModelMismatch:NO];
#endif
```

That means,If there is change in database model in DEBUG mode,they will simply delete older version of data model.I believe this has been fixed in latest version of Magical record.

If not, change it to

```
#ifdef DEBUG
[self setShouldDeleteStoreOnModelMismatch:NO];
#else
[self setShouldDeleteStoreOnModelMismatch:NO];
#endif
```

and fix migration code